# Is there any way to give ' important' to css property in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

My query is 'important' on 'color' is not working here. What is the way to give 'important' on CSS property in controller ? I want to override the bootstrap in-built property and want to override it using controller.

```
 $scope.red = function () {
      console.log("red");
      $scope.re = {
          'background-color': 'red',
          'color': {
          'black'
          '!important'
      };
 };
```

Comment: What about 'color':'black !important'; ?

Answer (score 1):

just add the `!important` in the same string as the color

```
$scope.red = function () {
   console.log("red");
   $scope.re = {
      'background-color': 'red',
      'color': 'black !important';
   }
}
```

Comment: it removes console error..but not hiding the bootstrap class

Comment: @SKalra - override it with what?

Comment: This is inbuit class and applies no effect of important    .nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #555;   not overriding this property

Comment: @SKalra - so you'd like to change the focus color? please try and be clear, don't just dump code

Comment: I want to change color from #555 to black

Comment: There may be a more specific definition of color for your element

Answer (score 0):

'black !important' is one value

try this

```
$scope.re = {
                'background-color': 'red',
                'color': {
                    'black !important'
                };
            }
```

Comment: it shows error at console..right way 'color': 'black !important'